# Efficient way to grow a large std::vector

Tags: c++14, stdvector

I'm filling a large (~100 to 1000MiB) `std::vector<char>` with data using `std::ifstream::read()`. I know the size of this read in advance, so I can construct the vector to that size.

Afterwards however, I keep reading from the file until I find a particular delimiter. Any data up to that delimiter is to be added to the vector. It's 500KiB at worst, usually *much* less.

Considering the vector's size, I'm wondering if this causes an expensive growth (and reallocation). Memory is an issue here, as the vector's size is to remain fairly close to that of its construction.

Is it a good solution to extend the vector's capacity slightly beyond its initial size using std::vector::reserve, so that the small amount of extra data doesn't require it to grow? If so, it's probably best to construct the vector empty, reserve the capacity and *then* resize it to its initial size, right?

Comment: Since C++11 you do have a [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) functions, so if you can spare the memory *temporarily* then you can reserve a larger size than ever needed, and then shrink it to fit. But be warned that this shrink probably causes a reallocation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, I'm aware of the possibility to use `shrink_to_fit`. Since the capacity will be minimally larger than the size, I think I can probably just leave the vector as is. From what I understand the unused capacity does not get in the way or regular usage (copying, iterating, etc.).

Comment: use 2 vectors. first one is the size of the file. the second one is allocated after finding the delimiter. 2 allocations.

Comment: @Aitch: For my code I need to have a single vector at the end though, so unless there's a way to append one to the other without reallocating the whole thing, I don't think that's preferable performance wise. Otherwise I'd agree and do an insert at the back or so.

Comment: do you need one vector or just a random access structure by index? you can encapsulate your two structures in one class, and provide iterators or the subscript operator [] as well. I bet you don't need it in this way.

Comment: @Aitch: I don't need to have a single vector in that sense. I'll keep your suggestion in mind, but if _construct, reserve, resize_ works the way I hope it does (hence my original question), I think it's preferable for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I agree. premature optimization is bad, but then create an empty vector and push_back all elements. this is more simpler.

Comment: Are you worried about physical memory or address space? I would expect a good implementation of `std::vector` to not commit any memory for elements that have never been constructed for this vector.

Comment: @dyp: Physical memory. If the vector is filled with say 500MiB of data, and 2KiB is pushed or inserted at the back, I don't want the C++ implementation to grow the capacity by a factor of 1.5 or something like that. That's what I'm worried about. Instead I thought _what if I just set its capacity to 501MiB from the get go_, which I know it'll never exceed. I'm just not sure if that works as I imagine.

Comment: I'd expect a good implementation to not *require 1.5 times the physical memory* when growing to insert some elements. Only when those elements are constructed will the physical memory be committed. (At least, that's what I'd expect. The libstdc++'s implementation on my machine seems to do that, combined with the default allocation mechanisms.)

Comment: @dyp: I see. That's where my understanding is lacking. I guess I'll read up some more on this and see if I can create a simple test whose results I can verify myself. Not worrying and just inserting the added data at the end would certainly be simpler.

Comment: Anyway, by reserving capacity for a vector, you only define a *lower limit*. Depending on the implementation, it could as well round up to the next step/level in its allocation scheme, which might produce the same capacity as when letting it grow automatically.

Comment: Since your data type is `char`, I'm assuming you are just copying raw bytes from the file. You might want to consider using `mmap()` (or check boost.interprocess/boost.iostreams for a portable implementation) instead of copying the file over, if the use case is acceptable.

Comment: Under 31.3.3. Size and Capacity  from The C++ Programming  language   says as follows: "It is tempting to assume that reserve() improves performance, but
the standard growth strategies for vector (§31.4.1.1) are so effective
that performance is rarely a good reason to use reserve(). Instead,
see reserve() as a way of increasing the predictability of performance
and for avoiding invalidation of iterators"

Comment: As another alternative besides the `mmap()` suggestion by DanielKO, have you considered scanning for the delimiter first so that you can allocate the exact size up front, with no subsequent adjustments?

At this scale and specificity of data type, it may also be worthwhile efficiency-wise to use `read()` directly instead of a stream that may not be fully specialized for this case. In both cases, you'd have to be reading from something that allows seeking - i.e. a file on disk supports that, but standard input doesn't.

Comment: @Novelocrat Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing. Start at the estimate, then seek forward to the delimiter and construct the vector to that size right away, then do a `read(charVec.data(), charVec.size());`. I guess I must have had a mental block not to consider this from the beginning.